# Failed to load Configuration from file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating a management system in MVC ASP.NET , and when I try to build the project I get this error:

> Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\Saad\source\repos\Tenent_Management_System\Tenent_Management_System\appsettings.json'.

This is the line where the error is shown

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

I tried to bring all the fresh code of the page `program.cs` but no luck.

How can I fix this?

[image: this the error message that is shown]

Comment: And your configuration file is?

Comment: {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"


}

Comment: its a appsettings.json

Comment: Your config file is correct, either restart your PC or check the output tab to make sure there is no other exception!

Comment: Please share the full exception text. Also when this does happen? How do.younstart the app?

Comment: TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Text.Json.JsonReaderHelper' threw an exception

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Buffers.SearchValues' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.


these are the two exceptions

And yes I have restarted the PC

Answer (score 1):

not sure this is the issue you have
but I couldn't load my appsettings.json file
so I added this nuget package: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json'
and made sure that in the file properties "copy to output directory" is set to "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 1):

Your appsettings.json file has an error. Pay attention to the green warnings. You may be missing a comma or quotation marks ( **,** or **"** ).